# Image header to fit in all email clients and browsers

Tags: html, css, html-email

Whats the secret here? I am have image that sits in on top of the emails. Its a rectangular bar runs full width. But it stretches all across in gmail and outlook but in the Mail client (mac) it works just fine. 
(picture is the black bar as you see below)

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td{
            font-size:1.2em;
            line-height:2;
        }
        .footer_add{
            font-size:0.9em;
            margin-top:2em;
            line-height:1;
        }
        .footer_content{
            font-size:0.9em;
            line-height:1;
        }           
        .footer_contactus{
            font-size:0.9em;
            line-height:1;
        }                       
    </style>    
</head>
<body style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
<div style="margin-top:-3em;">
    <img src="cid:email-header">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td style="overflow:hidden;height:0.5em"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo(COUNT_MSG_0. $receipient_display_name)?></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>                                                          
                <tr>
                    <td style="align:justify"><?php echo(COUNT_MSG_14.$sender_display_name.". ".COUNT_MSG_15); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo(COUNT_MSG_17);?></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>  
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>                                                                          
                <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1"><?php echo(COUNT_MSG_6); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1"><img src="cid:my-attach1" ><label style="font-family: Open Sans">Nottx</label></td>
                </tr>               
            </table>            
        </td>
    </tr>                                       
</table>

</body>
<footer>    
  <p class="footer_add">&nbsp; </p>
  <hr>
  <p class="footer_content">&nbsp; </p>
  <p class="footer_contactus">&nbsp; <?php echo(COUNT_MSG_99);?></p>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show a screen shot of what it is doing in Gmail, etc versus what it is supposed to look like? I am not sure exactly what the issue is from your description and seeing it may help.

Comment: Attached. As you can see below the picture. there is a huge scroll bar and users have to scroll to right

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `width` of the image to `100%` in your stylesheet:

```
img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: And you did apply it to the img element?
well if that don't i would solve it with @media queries

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the actual image size is over 1300px wide. Some email clients will stretch the image to the actual size of the image when set to 100% (Outlook being the major culprit).

The best solution would be to use a table instead of an image (if it is only a single colored bar that is going to be used). You can set width to 100% and height to whatever you need it to be and it will flow much better than an image and also will display even if image blocking is enabled.

Super simplified example: `<table width="100%" bgcolor="yourgreycolor"><tr><td height="50" style="font-size:50px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:100%;">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>`

If you need it to be an image, Outlook will break without a defined width or setting the actual size of the image to the max-width you want it displayed.

I would likely move it outside of a div and instead into the table you have below (table stylings are much more consistent) and I would make sure to include the HTML 'width' attribute on the image. (`<img width="100%" src="...`) and perhaps include a max-width on the email. Max-width is not read in some clients though (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css).

There are some other issues with your HTML and CSS that may not translate well into HTML email.  Please see below for some guides into how to design and develop HTML emails:

https://www.exacttarget.com/products/email-marketing/email-design-toolkit https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/ http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. unfortunately it did work for me, though i tried different variations.

Comment: Did you attempt using HTML/CSS instead of the image? or did you need it to be an image?